# CSS overflow slows down scrolling in mobile browsers

Tags: css, performance, scroll, overflow

When I use overflow:auto or overflow:hidden it slows down the scrolling in mobile browsers. I could not find any solutions rather than removing overflow settings.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: do you have some code to test?

Comment: @Vandervals thank you for your interest. I solved the problem. It is too complicated indeed. When I remove overflow settings, it worked well and later I tried other things. When I remove the border-radius from the div in which I scroll, the problem has gone again but the main problem was "border-radius".